# Regarding basis of regular functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety. Let us define a $\mathbb{Q}$-open set of X to be a union of sets of the form

$
D(f) = \{x \in X| f(x) \neq 0\},\,\, f \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]
$

Let us define the $\mathbb{Q}$-regular functions on a $\mathbb{Q}$-open set $U$ to be functions such that at every $x \in U$ there exists $U_x \subset U$ s.t $x \in U_x$ and $f = \frac{p}{q}$ on $U_x$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. We will denote the $\mathbb{Q}$-regular functions on $U$ by
$\mathcal{O}(U)(\mathbb{Q})$

Now we know from standard results that $\mathcal{O}(D(f)) = \mathbb{C}[X]_f =
\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}[X]_f$.

We also know that $\mathbb{Q}[X]_f = \mathcal{O}(D(f))(\mathbb{Q})$.

My question is do we know that for an arbitrary $\mathbb{Q}$-open set $U$ that
$\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathcal{O}(U)(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathcal{O}(U)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Two questions: do you assume that $X$ is defined over $\Bbb Q$? What base ring do you take for $\Bbb A^1$?

Comment: I am taking the base ring to be $\mathbb{C}$. I don't assume that $X$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ but I wouldn't mind assuming it as I am just trying to get some intuition about this stuff! Thanks

Comment: Did you have try to work on the stalks?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately (unless I missed it). This question is inspired by the first chapter of Linear Algebraic Groups by T.A Springer, where it covers only the basics of what an affine variety is